# Java: Testing algorithms: all possible combinations

Tags: java, algorithm, testing

I want to exhaustively test a String matching algorithm, named myAlgo(Char[] a, Char[] b)

The exhaustive test includes a no. of different char letters, alplhabet " l ", in an "n" long array. The test then computes all combinations, while comparing it with all combinations of another array with similar properties (Like truth tables),e.g.

I have not been able to either compute something that would generate every combination of the array of size n and alphabet l, niether have I been able to make code that is able to combine the computation into iterative testcases (test all the combinations of the two arrays compared), though with code that would be able to generate the combinations, making a nested for-loop should do the required testing.

My goal is to break my algorithm by making it compute something it should not compute.

```
Test(char[] l, int n)
    l = [a;b] //a case could be
    n = 2     //a case could be
    myAlgo([a;a],[a;a]); //loops over my algorithm in the following way
    myAlgo([a;b],[a;a]);
    myAlgo([b;a],[a;a]);
    myAlgo([b;b],[a;a]);
    myAlgo([a;a],[a;b]);
    myAlgo([a;b],[a;b]);
    myAlgo([b;a],[a;b]);
    myAlgo([b;b],[a;b]);
    myAlgo([a;a],[b;a]);
    myAlgo([a;b],[b;a]);
    ...
    myAlgo([b;b],[b;b]);
```

My own solution (only works for a finite set of "l") and also starts printing wierd outputs on later iterations.

public class Test {

```
//aux function to format chars
public static String concatChar(char [] c){
    String s = "";
    for(char cc : c){
        s += cc;
    }
    return s;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String ss1 = "AA";                          //TestCases, n = 2
    String ss2 = "AA";
    char[] test1 = ss1.toCharArray();
    char[] test2 = ss2.toCharArray();
    Fordi fordi = new Fordi();                  //my algorithm
    TestGenerator tGen = new TestGenerator();   //my testGenerator
    for(int i=0; i<Math.pow(4.0, 2.0);i++){     //to test all different cases

        for(int j=0; j<Math.pow(4.0, 2.0);j++){
            int k = fordi.calculate(test1, test2);  //my algorithm
            String mys1 = concatChar(test1);        //to print result
            String mys2 = concatChar(test2);        //to print result
            System.out.println(mys1 + " - " + mys2);
            System.out.println(k);
            test2 = tGen.countArray(test2);         //"flip" one number
        }
        test2 = ss1.toCharArray();
        test1 = tGen.countArray(test1);             //"flip"
    }
}
```

}

My  arrayflipper code:

```
public char[] countArray(char[] a){
    int i=0;
    while(i<a.length){
        switch (a[i]){
        case 'A':
            a[i]='B';
            clearBottom(a,i);
            return a;
        case 'B':
            a[i]='C';
            clearBottom(a,i);
            return a;
        case 'C':
            a[i]='D';
            clearBottom(a,i);
            return a;
        case 'D':
            i++;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Something went terribly wrong!");

        }
    }
    return a;

}
public char[] clearBottom(char [] a, int i){
    while(i >0){
        i--;
        a[i] = 'A';
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking - i as well dont see the connection between having all of the variations possible and the bit flip algorithm (but i dont know that algo quite well).

Comment: You are welcome - it is already much clearer what you trying to archive - hence my upvote to get you back on track. Now where EXACTLY are you stuck at? Like do you have problems generating all different combinations? Or is it that you are able to generate all those combinations but dont know how to dynamicially generate testcases out of it? Or is it that both the combinations as well as the calls are already working but your `myAlgo` method does not work as expected? (in the last case we would have to see the `myAlgo` method while in the other cases its not realy of interest.

Comment: The first two, I have added it to the post.

Comment: And there you go - asking me that is o.k. like so - but one last thing that will defently prevent you from further downvotes and have a good SO question is to add "your efforts/ what you tried so faar". Doing so will prevent other SOs (i wonder where all of them hide - they LOVE downvoting) from assuming youre just asking for a entire solution without any effort of your side. (I by the way wont have time until the next Wednesday to dig into it - sorry).

Comment: Well since you (just like me) didnt read the terms&conditions you will likely get more downvotes (but as well a good impression whats required to stop the downvotes :D:D). Now you have a bulletproof SO question ;) (Note i havent yet took a look at your code ;))

Comment: Clear and crisp communication(especially when so technical) is a challenge, but thanks for the hints :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, your goal is to create all n-character long strings (stored individually as elements in an array) consisting of letters in the L letter alphabet?

One way to accomplish this is to order your letters (A=0, B=1, C=2, etc).  Then you can, from a starting string of AAA...AAA (n-characters long) just keep adding 1.  Essentially you implement an addition algorithm.  Adding 1 would turn an A=0 into a B=1.  For example, n=3 and L=3:

start: AAA (0,0,0).

Adding 1 becomes AAB (0,0,1)

Adding 1 again become AAC (0, 0, 2)

Adding 1 again (since we are out of letters, now we carry a bit over) ABA (0, 1, 0).

You can boil the process down to looking for the right-most number that is not maxed out and add 1 to it (then all digits to the right of that digit go back to zero).  So in the string ABCCC, the B digit is the right-most not maxed out digit, it goes up by 1 and becomes a C, then all the maxed out digits to the right go back to 0 (A) leaving ACAAA as the next string.

Your algorithm just repeatedly adds 1 until all the elements in the string are maxed out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a switch statement, I recommend putting every character you want to test (A, B, C, D) into an array, and then using the XOR operation to calculate the index of each character from the iteration number in a manner similar to the following:

```
char[] l = new char[]{'A','B','C','D'};
int n = 2;
char[] test1 = new char[n];
char[] test2 = new char[n];
int max = (int)Math.pow(l.length, n);
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        test2[k] = l[(i % (int)Math.pow(l.length, k + 1)) / (int)Math.pow(l.length, k)];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            test1[k] = l[(j % (int)Math.pow(l.length, k + 1)) / (int)Math.pow(l.length, k)];
        }
        int k = fordi.calculate(test1, test2);
        System.out.println(new String(test1) + "-" + new String(test2));
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

You can add more characters to `l` as well as increase `n` and it should still work. Of course, this can be further optimized, but you should get the idea. Hope this answer helps!